# Чем плох и хорош "Анимированный" background?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Вот тут [на сайте](http://novka780.wixsite.com/massajbad/)
используется в качестве фона `.mp4` (и по моему еще какой-то подстраховочный видео формат). Хотелось бы узнать в чем минусы такой реализации?

Может проводились исследования, или опросы, которые могут ответить на вопросы:

- Какая анимация будет приемлема?
- Уместна ли вообще в заднем фоне анимация?

Comment: Может вопрос и дискуссионный, но мне нужно было узнать не устарели ли мои взгляды на то, что анимация сильно отвлекает и перегружает страницу.Мало ли, может инет уже в запредельных скоростях, а пользователям с синдромом гиперактивности нравится, что на фоне что-то мелькает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Плюсы:

1. Видео на фоне выглядит круто
2. Видео на фоне выглядит свежо
3. Вообще, фоновое видео добавляет вес и солидность сайту или пытается)

Минусы:

1. Видео много весит
2. Видео тормозит на слабых машинах
3. Видео отвлекает от контента

Выводы:

Использовать нужно очень осторожно. Фоновое видео отлично подходит для промо-сайтов для создания вау-эффекта. Такой сайт-однодневка для рекламы продукта и не более.

Answer (score 0):

В общем-то тема использования анимированного фона поднималась кучу раз со времен существования еще Flash и ответ однозначный - нет, это плохая практика. С точки зрения дизайна подобный формат поднесения информации является крайне негативным. Движущиеся элементы, ровно как и ярко красные, забирают все внимание на себя. Уже спустя пять минут, проведенном на таком сайте и попыток чтения, ваши глаза начнут уставать, внимательность теряться и сайт начнет только нервировать. Несмотря на то, что это кажется круто, после непродолжительного использования весь эффект уходит в никуда и начинается обратная реакция.

Приведу цитаты из книги Стива Круга.

> Многим не нравится плохое применение интективных элементов, большие и
>   сложные анимации, которые долго загружаются и кажутся бесполезными.
>   Если вы внимательно расспросите этих людей, задавая правильные
>   вопросы, то, скорее всего, узнаете, что этим же самым людям
>   понравились бы сайты с небольшими и тщательно разработанными
>   элементами, которые оживляли бы содержание страниц и добавляли к ним
>   полезную функциональность, при этом не «вставая поперек дороги».

Если Вы решили использовать интерактивные элементы на своей странице, то постарайтесь сделать так, что бы они были полезными и функциональными. В противном случае их лучше не использовать.

Comment: При беглом поиске Стива Круга в гугле видно, что его книги вышли где-то в 2010. Если я ошибаюсь подскажите его самые современные работы, а то за 6 лет многое уже и устареть могло.

Comment: @Илья, по дате выхода книг смотрите лучше amazon, там и отзывы есть - последнее переиздание январь 2014 года. А вообще я говорю, эта тема поднималась еще с 2004 года, когда это было можно очень. Но если хотите получить свежие знания, ищите англоязычные статьи Animation in Web Design или книги по Usability.